# JOGL canvas in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt, jogl

I'm having issues getting JOGL canvas/panel in JavaFX scene. My assumption was, that if JOGL GLCanvas adheres to contract for awt.Canvas, there should be no issue in placing it in JFX scene.

I got together following code (all snippets are inside JFX Application::start).

First creation of JOGL "hello world" (pulsating background just to see if things render and move):

```
GLCanvas glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
glCanvas.setSize(size-10, size-10);
glCanvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {
    private final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        new Thread(() -> {while (true) glCanvas.display();}).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL4 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL4();
        float t = (float)(Math.sin((System.currentTimeMillis()-t0)/1000f)+1)/2f;
        gl.glClearColor(t, 1-t, 0, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
});

GLJPanel glPanel = new GLJPanel();
glPanel.add(glCanvas);
glPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

Alternative hello world (no moving, this clearly works):

```
Canvas awtCanvas = new Canvas() {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());}
};
awtCanvas.setSize(size-10, size-10);

JPanel swingPanel = new JPanel();
swingPanel.add(awtCanvas);
swingPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

And test code putting things together:

```
if (jfx) {
    SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    swingNode.setContent(swingPanel);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(swingNode), size, size+30));
    primaryStage.show();
} else {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(size, size+30);
    frame.add(swingPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Reference solutions *JFrame(Panel(Canvas()))*, *JFrame(JPanel(GLCanvas()))*, and *JFrame(GLJPanel(GLCanvas()))* work as expected (sort of, *GLPanel* seems to ignore background color setting).

When I try the non-JOGL wrapper *Stage(Scene(Group(JPanel(Canvas())))*, works as expected (JFX works).

Now for JOGL, wrapper *Stage(Scene(Group(JPanel(GLJPanel(GLCanvas()))))* produces black where canvas content should be. Wrapper *Stage(Scene(Group(JPanel(GLCanvas())))* (skipping use of GLJPanel) will not produce black square for canvas content, and I only get blue square for JPanel.

The only mentions I found on the internet are from 2012/2013 where it seems it does not work (but it also seems SwingNode did not exist at the time), and 2016 on JOGL forums that links to dead link in bugzzila.

Comment: Even if it would work - preformance would very very bad. The real solution to all this that JavaFX needs to gets a DirectRendering-Node, where you draw with whatever technology you want to draw (JOGL, LWJGL, Native, ...).

There are currently discussions on getting such a Node implemented so subscribe to the openjfx-Mailing lists (or you might want to follow my blog) see if this is coming true

Comment: Rather give a try to NewtCanvasJFX (since JOGL 2.4): https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/newt/classes/com/jogamp/newt/javafx/NewtCanvasJFX.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of sheer desperation tried to use GLJPanel instead of GLCanvas, and it works. Sort of.

There is issue with SwingNode resize - it has a bug that does not allow easy resize ([OracleJDK](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8154846) has the bug for quite some time, [OpenJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8120292) seems to have it solved)

Suggested solution to the resize issue is to put width/height property listener on Scene and reinsert the canvas on each size change:

```
Dimension dim = new Dimension((int)scene.getWidth(), (int)scene.getHeight());
ChangeListener<Number> stageSizeListener = (obs, prev, next) -> {
    dim.setSize(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
    component.setSize(dim);
    swingNode.setContent(swingPanel);
};
scene.heightProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
scene.widthProperty().addListener(stageSizeListener);
```

This works with code in the question, but each reinsert triggers *dispose(GL)* and *init(GL)* cycle which might be ok for some applications, not in my case.

Decided to do a little hack, making the GLJPanel in size of some maximum allowed resolution (say 4K, I render to off screen buffer first anyway), rendering in desired resolution, blitting the result in top-left corner of the panel, and clipping the panel within JFX scene to that very same resolution.

As **tomsontom** mentioned, the performance is not exactly great, *GLJPanel* is much slower than *GLCanvas* by itself (from 800FPS to 40FPS at 4K), and when in *SwingNode* it gets even worse (17FPS at 4K). Will postpone use of JFX as far as possible, and hopefully they either get *SwingNode* fixed in upcoming separation from JDK, or even get the *DirectRenderingNode*.

Comment: The real problem is explained in our bug tracker, there is no equivalent of Java AWT Native Interface for OpenJFX/JavaFX, it prevents us from implementing a lasting solution whereas we did it for AWT, SWT and Swing.

Comment: @gouessej Has this changed at all as of 2020? Getting JOGL to work with JavaFX.

Comment: @BAR Yes, it's better with JOGL >= 2.4.0 as there is com.jogamp.newt.javafx.NewtCanvasJFX but there are still some limitations. By the way, if you have JOGL specific questions to ask, rather do it on our official forum as only a very few contributors are on StackOverflow. I forgot to mention this: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=607